# ReactJS.Net on MVC5 fails to resolve dependency

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, inversion-of-control, reactjs, tinyioc, reactjs.net

I'm trying to set up an ASP.Net MV5 application to work with [ReactJS.Net](http://reactjs.net), including server side rendering and bundling.

Unfortunately, it fails with this exception:

> An exception of type 'React.TinyIoC.TinyIoCResolutionException' occurred in React.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to resolve type: React.ReactEnvironment

This exception occurs on this line:

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ui-components")
```

This line is taken my `_layouts.cshtml` file.

**How should I solve my issue?**

---

To give of details, here what I've done:

1. in BundleConfig.cs:

   ```
       bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/reactjs").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/react/react-{version}.js"));
       bundles.Add(new JsxBundle("~/bundles/ui-components")
                   .Include("~/content/ui/components/*.jsx"));
   ```

   I created a folder "Content/ui/components" with all my jsx files (actually only one "commentsbox.jsx" file taken from the tutorial.
2. In ReactConfig.cs, I removed the `WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod` attribute, because I've this is no more supported with MVC5, in profit of Owin component. It stills contains :

   ```
   public static class ReactConfig
   {
       public static void Configure()
       {
           ReactSiteConfiguration.Configuration
               .AddScript("~/content/ui/*.jsx");
       }
   }
   ```
3. In my `Global.asax.cs` file, I explicitly call `ReactConfig.Configure` method to replace the `WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod` hook:

   ```
   public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
   {
       protected void Application_Start()
       {
           ReactConfig.Configure();
           AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
           FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
           RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
           BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
       }
   }
   ```
4. My `_layouts.cshtml` view contains (at the bottom of the file):

   ```
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/reactjs")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ui-components")
   @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
   @Html.ReactInitJavaScript()
   ```
5. In one of my view:

   ```
   @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
   }

   <div id="content"></div>      

   @section scripts
   {
       @Html.React("CommentBox", new {}, containerId:"content")        
   }
   ```
6. And finally, my jsx file:

   ```
   var CommentBox = React.createClass({
     render: function() {
       return (
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-4">
               hello
               </div>

           </div>
       );
     }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the source of my problem.

Actually, the error message was misleading. In `ReactConfig.Configure` method, wildcard does not works (i.e. `*.jsx` does not works).

I replaced the method with this:

```
public static void Configure()
{
    ReactSiteConfiguration.Configuration
        .AddScript("~/content/ui/commentsbox.jsx").
        .AddScript("~/content/ui/comment.jsx");
}
```

and it solved the issue.

Comment: Good point, the error message could probably be more descriptive. I think a better message is hiding in an InnerException somewhere. There's a Github issue for allowing wildcards: https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/issues/60