# ReactJS NET on MVC5 fails to resolve dependency

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, reactjs.net

I have the same problem as mentioned in the following question here:

[ReactJS.Net on MVC5 fails to resolve dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150323/reactjs-net-on-mvc5-fails-to-resolve-dependency)

Everything in this question is exactly the same, and just as descriptive. However, this question must be answered again, because of the following reasons:

I have the latest dll with the applied fix (latest React.NET dlls):

```
<package id="React.Core" version="1.5.5" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="react.js" version="0.13.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="React.Web" version="1.5.5" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="React.Web.Mvc4" version="1.5.5" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="System.Web.Optimization.React" version="1.5.5" targetFramework="net45" />
```

The project works on 3 of my machines (local, dev server, QA server). But when I tried to deploy to production, I got stuck the following error message:

> [JsRuntimeException: Object doesn't support this property or method]
>   MsieJavaScriptEngine.ActiveScript.ActiveScriptJsEngineBase.InvokeScript(Action
>   action) +161
>   JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie.MsieJsEngine.InnerExecute(String code)

...

> [TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type:
>   React.JavaScriptEngineFactory]

...

> [TinyIoCResolutionException: Unable to resolve type:
>   React.ReactEnvironment]

This is running on IIS7.5, and I just upgraded to .net 4.5.

Is there any other missing requirements I should be looking at?

Comment: Hmm, it sounds like something is going wrong with MsieJavaScriptEngine. It might be worth posting an issue to its Github page: https://github.com/Taritsyn/MsieJavaScriptEngine. Alternatively, you could force usage of V8 (call `.SetAllowMsieEngine(false)` in your `ReactConfig`) and see what errors ClearScript is throwing. The MSIE engine is only used as a fallback if V8 fails to initialise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out:

Go to IIS, application pool, and go to the pool you're using for your website, then click advantage settings:

Make sure your Enable 32-Bit Applications is set to TRUE.

Personally, I'm not sure why this works, but it does. Especially from the standpoint that if I removed the JSX files, the site worked. But I needed my react components :-/

In **powershell** <sup>[1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rakkimk/2007/11/03/iis7-running-32-bit-and-64-bit-asp-net-versions-at-the-same-time-on-different-worker-processes/)</sup>:

```
& "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" set apppool /apppool.name:DefaultAppPool /enable32BitAppOnWin64:true
```

where `DefaultAppPool` is the name of your application pool.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that on a production server installed Internet Explorer 8 or below. Install a Internet Explorer 9 or above.